Flatlist doesnt change value
I have this code, here. It runs fine, when i run the function refreshfun i properly get the data {"distances": [0.0075434814339333765, 0.004403247515871494], "names": ["George", "Markou"]}
But i also want to set the value from my list into this data, but for some reason it doesnt.


    function Homepage({navigation}) {
      const [name, setName] = useState('');
      const [followers, setFollower] = useState('');
      const [Places, setPlaces] = useState('');
      const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(0);
      const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
      const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
      const [data, setData] = useState([]); //initiates the state of the list

      useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
          if (status !== 'granted') {
            setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
            return;
          }

          let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
          setLocation(location);
        })();
      }, []);

      let text = 'Waiting..';
      if (errorMsg) {
        text = errorMsg;
      } else if (location) {
        text = `Latitude: ${location.coords.latitude}, Longitude: ${location.coords.longitude}`;
      }

//properly runs and gets the right values but doesnt setData right

      async function refreshfun(sliderValue, latitude, longitude) { 
        try {
            const output = await refreshscript(sliderValue, latitude, longitude);
            console.log("Output from API:", output);


            if (Array.isArray(output.names) && Array.isArray(output.distances) && output.names.length === output.distances.length) {
                const newData = output.names.map((name, index) => ({
                    id: index + 1,
                    name: name,
                    distance: output.distances[index]
                }));

                console.log("New data to set:", newData); 
                setData(newData); // Update the state with the new data
            } else {
                console.error("Invalid output from API:", output);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        }
    }


      




      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          const data = await loadhomepagescript();
          console.log('User Name:', data.user_name);
          console.log('Places:', data.places);
          console.log('Followers:', data.followers);

          setName(String(data.user_name));
          setFollower(parseInt(data.places));
          setPlaces(parseInt(data.followers));

        };

        const fetchSliderValue = async () => {
          try {
            const slidervaluetouse = await AsyncStorage.getItem('slidervalue');
            if (slidervaluetouse !== null) {
              setSliderValue(Number(slidervaluetouse));
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching slider value:', error);
          }
        };

        fetchSliderValue();

        fetchData();
      }, []);




//renders list
      const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <View style={styles.item}>
          <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
      );


      return (
        <View style={styles.homepage}>
         
            <View style={styles.uinfo}>
              <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'left' }}>{name}</Text>
              <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'left' }}>{followers}</Text>
              <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'left' }}>{Places}</Text>
            </View>
            <Text>{text}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.sliderValueText}>Find people near: {sliderValue.toFixed(1)}</Text>
            <Slider
            style={styles.slider}
            minimumValue={0}
            maximumValue={50}
            value={sliderValue}
            onValueChange={(value) => setSliderValue(value)}
            minimumTrackTintColor="black"
            maximumTrackTintColor="gray"
            thumbTintColor="#009fe1"
          />

    <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
//flatlist which doesnt get the right data(doesnt get any data inside her   
 <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()} // Ensure key is a string
        numColumns={3} // Display three items in each row
        contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContainer}
    />
        </ScrollView>

          
        <View style={styles.menu}>
        <Button title='R' onPress={() => refreshfun(sliderValue,location.coords.latitude,location.coords.longitude)}>
        </Button>

        <Button title='Settings' onPress={() => gotosettings(navigation) }>

          </Button>
        </View>
          
        </View>

      );
    }



The code runs without errors etc. The data i get from a node.js server and i get it right without any errors etc, i just cant load the data into the list. I want the list to have as many elements as
"sets on my data" for instance the first distance goes with the first name etc
